# How to get all the colums using one-one and one-many and other in NotORM and PHP?

Tags: php, orm, fiddler

Here is what I have done:

```
$meetups = $db->meetups()->where("ID > ?", "15");
    foreach ($meetups as $meetup) {
        $location[] = $meetup->locations();
    }

    echo json_encode($locations[0]->getIterator());
```

As shown in the above snippet I'm trying to output the JSON string of the meetup location and using fiddler I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method NotORM_MultiResult::getIterator() in C:\xampp\htdocs\latest\Server\Routes\Meetups.php on line 204
```

What am I doing wrong? This works well:

```
$meetups = $db->meetups()->where("ID > ?", "15");
        foreach ($meetups as $meetup) {
            $location[] = $meetup->locations['Title'];
        }

        echo json_encode($locations);
```

But I don't want to get just Title of the location. I want all the columns.

My table structure is:

meetups table

> ID, Title, locations_ID, ...

locations table

```
ID, Title, LocationLat, LocationLng, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that the `$locations[0]` object doesn't offer a `getIterator()` method.

That object has a method called `jsonSerialize`, a property called `jsonAsArray`, and a `$rows` property.

Answer (score 0):

From NotORM FAQ:

> *How to create a plain array from NotORM result?*
>
> You can use iterator_to_array:
>
> `// inner call converts the rows, outer call converts the fields`
>   `array_map('iterator_to_array', iterator_to_array($db->application()));`

Your code may be as well reduced to this one-liner:

```
echo json_encode(array_map('iterator_to_array', iterator_to_array($db->meetups('ID > ?', 15))));
```